# Overlapping Label in UITableView on iOS 8 but not in iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios7, ios8

It seems that a label (lblscore) is overlapping if I run my app on iOS8 but not in iOS 7. When I check it, the `cell.addSubviews(lblscore)` caused it but I cannot delete it because if I do, that label will not be displayed at all. I'm not using a storyboard.

this is my codes in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    var i = 0
    var lblname = UILabel()
    var lblmsg = UILabel()
    let row = indexPath.row
    var forName = ""
    var forScore = 0
    if let not_me = threads[row]["not_me"] as? NSDictionary{
        if let username = not_me["username"] as? String{
            forName = username
        }
        if let score = threads[row]["partner_score"] as? Int{
            forScore = score
        }
        if (not_me == [:]){
            if let username = defaults.valueForKey("username") as? String{
                forName = username
            }
            if let score = threads[row]["author_score"] as? Int{
                forScore = score
            }
        }
    }
    for sub in cell.subviews{
        if (sub.subviews.count>6){
            for sub1 in sub.subviews{
                i++
                if ((i>0) && !(i==7)){
                    switch (i){
                    case 3:
                        lblmsg = sub1 as! UILabel
                        lblmsg.text = ""
                        lblmsg.text = threads[row]["content"] as? String
                        lblmsg.sizeToFit()
                    case 4:
                        lblname = sub1 as! UILabel
                        lblname.text = ""
                        lblname.sizeToFit()
                        lblname.text = forName
                        lblname.sizeToFit()
                        lblname.frame = CGRectMake(40, 10, lblname.bounds.width, lblname.bounds.height+4)
                        lblmsg.frame = CGRectMake(40, lblname.bounds.height-5, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-100,50)
                    case 5:
                        let lbldate : UILabel = sub1 as! UILabel
                        lbldate.text = ""
                        lbldate.sizeToFit()
                        lbldate.text = threads[row]["timeAgo"] as? String
                        lbldate.sizeToFit()
                        lbldate.frame = CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/3*2, 15, lbldate.bounds.width, 15)
                    case 6:
                        let lblscore : UILabel = sub1 as! UILabel
                        lblscore.text = ""
                        lblscore.sizeToFit()
                        lblscore.text = "\(forScore)"
                        lblscore.sizeToFit()
                        if(lblscore.bounds.width == 15){
                            lblscore.frame = CGRectMake(lblname.bounds.width+50, 10, lblscore.bounds.width+5, lblscore.bounds.height+4)}
                        else{
                            lblscore.frame = CGRectMake(lblname.bounds.width+50, 10, lblscore.bounds.width+10, lblscore.bounds.height+4)}
                    default:
                        print("")
                    }
                }
                if (i==7){
                    let btnDelete = sub1 as! UIButton
                    btnDelete.tag = row
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            cell.alpha = 0
            let lblscore = UILabel()
            let btnDelete = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-18, 22.5, 22, 30))
            btnDelete.tag = row
            btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: "openDeleteBar:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            lblscore.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (102/255), green: (193/255), blue: (144/255), alpha: 1)
            btnDelete.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "grayBin")!)
            lblname.text = forName
            lblname.sizeToFit()
            lblscore.text = "\(forScore)"
            lblscore.sizeToFit()
            lblname.frame = CGRectMake(40, 10, lblname.bounds.width, lblname.bounds.height+4)
            let lblmsg = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40, lblname.bounds.height-5, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-100,50))
            lblmsg.text = threads[row]["content"] as? String
            if(lblscore.bounds.width == 15){
                lblscore.frame = CGRectMake(lblname.bounds.width+40, 10, lblscore.bounds.width+5, lblscore.bounds.height+4)}
            else{
                lblscore.frame = CGRectMake(lblname.bounds.width+40, 10, lblscore.bounds.width+10, lblscore.bounds.height+4)}
            lblscore.layer.borderWidth = 1
            lblscore.clipsToBounds = true
            lblscore.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            lblscore.textAlignment = .Center
            let lbldate = UILabel()
            lbldate.text = threads[row]["timeAgo"] as? String
            lbldate.sizeToFit()
            lbldate.frame = CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/3*2, 15, lbldate.bounds.width, 15)
            lblname.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 15)
            lblmsg.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 13)
            lbldate.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 13)
            lblscore.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 15)
            lbldate.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            lblmsg.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            lblscore.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.selectionStyle = .None
            cell.addSubview(lblmsg)
            cell.addSubview(lblname)
            cell.addSubview(lbldate)
                cell.addSubview(lblscore)
            cell.addSubview(btnDelete)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: {
                cell.alpha = 1
                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: From a readability standpoint, you should use camelCase for your `let`/`var` statements. Also, giving your `let`/`var`s more descriptive names also would aid greatly in readability. Ex: `let labelScore = UILabel()` instead of `let lblscore = UILabel()`

Comment: My Eyes!  They Burn!  Are you using a storyboard?  If so, please use a prototype cell with auto layout and constraints.  Setting things based on screen boundaries is prone to failure.

Comment: Replace all that code with a custom cell subclass and prototype cells in a Storyboard. Also, don't use hardcoded font sizes - use Dynamic Types. And try not to use non-standard fonts - use the system font that Apple has provided.

Comment: I'm not using storyboard. I'm sorry I haven't noticed that I didn't use camel case when doing that since it was on rush but I got too tired to change it. The font is from the client so I don't have a hold to it.

Comment: Mmmh, `Roboto` typeface... Are you porting code from android? ;)

Comment: not from android but from another language.

Comment: Can I see your project?

Comment: Sorry I need 10 reputations to add image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help anyone with this situation. I found the solution by myself. Since my app can run in iOS 8 and iOS 7, the first thing to do is identify the version then identify the cell. To know if the cell is empty ,'cell == nil' will never work since a cell already have 2 subviews (content view and separator) in iOS8. In iOS 7 before you get the cell you have to go through it's wrapper.

to further explain...

```
let version = "\(Array(String(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion))[0])"//get device version
if (version == "7"){//if iOS 7
    for wrapper in cell.subviews{//go to the wrapper
        if (wrapper.subviews.count==2){//if the wrapper contains the content view and the separator only
            //Here you will add the contents of the cell
        }
        else{//if wrapper has more subview which indicate that it is already filled
        var i = 0
                for sub in wrapper.subviews{//scan all subviews of wrapper
                    i++
                    if (i>2){//delete items 3 and beyond since the content view and separator is in the first 2
                        sub.removeFromSuperview()//remove them
                    }
                }
                //Here you will add the contents of the cell
        }
}
}
else{//if iOS 8
if (cell.subviews.count==2){//if the cell contains the content view and the separator only
            //Here you will add the contents of the cell
        }
        else{//if cell has more subview which indicate that it is already filled
        var i = 0
                for sub in cell.subviews{//scan all subviews of wrapper
                    i++
                    if (i>2){//delete items 3 and beyond since the content view and separator is in the first 2
                        sub.removeFromSuperview()//remove them
                    }
                }
                //Here you will add the contents of the cell
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the the table tries to reuse a cell, it will delete the contents of that cell before adding the new contents. I hope this will help many.